# Passing Stripe Client Intent Secret to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments

I need to pass the Stripe Client Intent secret to Javascript to execute some code. I am displaying it like this at the moment. But this is probably not a very secure way of passing the info.

```
<input type="hidden" id="intent_data_client_secret" value="{{ $intent_data_client_secret }}">
```

According to the Stripe documentation linked here: [https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#:~:text=The%20client%20secret%20can%20be,that%20includes%20the%20client%20secret](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#:%7E:text=The%20client%20secret%20can%20be,that%20includes%20the%20client%20secret).

> The client secret can be used to complete the payment process with the
> amount specified on the PaymentIntent. It should not be logged,
> embedded in URLs, or exposed to anyone other than the customer. Make
> sure that you have TLS enabled on any page that includes the client
> secret.

What are some better ways of passing secure tokens to javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a fine approach, and you can see an example of this under the "Server-side rendering" tab of the [example integration guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web-create-payment-intent).

**Template**:

```
<button id="card-button" data-secret="{{ client_secret }}">
  Submit Payment
</button>
```

**Server code**:

```
app.get('/checkout', async (req, res) => {
  const intent = // ... Fetch or create the PaymentIntent
  res.render('checkout', { client_secret: intent.client_secret });
});
```

The alternative would be what's in the same guide under the "single page application" tab, making a client-side request to your own backend/api to retrieve the secret for Payment Intent or Checkout Session:

**Client**:

```
var response = fetch('/secret').then(...)
```

**Server**:

```
app.get('/secret', async (req, res) => {
  const intent = // ... Fetch or create the PaymentIntent
  res.json({client_secret: intent.client_secret});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense